# How to configure a transaction timeout for just one method on a Weblogic server?

Tags: java, hibernate, configuration, weblogic, weblogic12c

I have a periodically executed task, that exceeds the configured transaction timeout.

```
@Schedule(dayOfWeek="*", hour="0")
public void doStuff() {

}
```

I cannot just set the transaction timeout for the whole weblogic server in the services/JTA section to a higher value, because it should stay at 30 seconds for all the other transactions that happen in the application and in other applications deployed on that WLS instance.
I also cannot set the `TransactionAttributeType` of the `@TransactionAttribute`-annotation to `NOT_SUPPORTED` like suggested in related questions, because I need to write to the database in the scheduled `doStuff`-method and I get an `EJBTransactionRequiredException` if I try that without a transaction.

I am using Hibernate as JPA framework and JEE7.

Is there a way to configure a higher transaction timeout just for that method without changing the transaction timeout for any other beans deployed on the WLS?